# is it possible to use laravel without composer dump-autload?

Tags: php, laravel, directory

since I have made an other folder structure than the standard laravel folder structure i now have to do `composer dump-autoload` whenever i create a new controller in the cms layer, in the app layer it will be able to find that controller without `composer dump-autoload`.
Is it possible to remove that and let it always find the controller that i'm looking for?
Thanks

my folder structure is like this:

```
doc root\
---- app
-------- controller
-------- views

---- cms
-------- controller
-------- views

---- public
---- vendor
```

Comment: You need to provide further information.

Comment: I already tried that and that does not change my problem, i still have to do composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloading if you don't want to run `composer dump-autoload` everytime you add a new file (for example a controller).

Create a new folder in `app` named `Acme`. In that folder you create more folders, `Controllers` and `Models`.

Now you edit your composer file with PSR-4 autoloading by adding this to your `autoload` section:

```
"psr-4": {
    "Acme\\": "app/Acme"
}
```

After editing the file you need to run `composer dump-autoload` (you only need to do this once, not after adding a new file inside the `Acme` folder).

Now you are free to add files you want to use. The only important thing you need to remember is to use `namespace Acme\Path\To\File;` at the start of each file. So if you where to add a controller inside `Acme\Controllers` named `TestController` you would need it to be like this:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Controllers;

class TestController extends \BaseController {
    // Methods here
}
```

Read more about namespaces [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).